# How can I count the no. of subsequences that have the product of elements smaller or equal a number D?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

How can I count the no. of subsequences of an array that have the product of elements smaller or equal a number `D` without counting the empty subsequence?

For example :

`array=[2,2,2,3,4,10]
D=50`

The answer should be 39. I tried with backtracking, but it's not so faster.
All number in the array are smaller or equal with `D` and bigger than `0`.

Comment: Can you post your code? What is the problem with it? 1.) Do you get an incorrect result, 2.) do you get no result because of the program running too long, or 3.) do you get the correct result but you want a faster program?

Comment: If D is small enough, you might be able to get away with simple dynamic programming

Comment: D ≤ 200.000 ! @NiklasB. That I want. But I don't know how to write that ! How will be the algorithm in pseudocod?

Comment: And what is the maximum number of the elements in the array?

Comment: @AndreaDusza 200.000

Comment: Ok so I think one interesting observation is that you can ignore the 1s in your array for now and multiply the final result by 2^(# of 1s). Then each subsequence with product < D will have size at most log_2 D elements. Not sure how this yields an efficient algorithm though. The DP recurrence I had in mind can be solved in O(N * D), but that's too slow apparently

Comment: @NiklasB. I was wrong . The product  must be ≤ D

Comment: @NiklasB. When you ignore the 1s in the sequence, you need to be careful with the empty sequence.  You first need to include it, then multiply with 2^(# of 1s), and finally subtract the empty subsequence again.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Exactly.

Comment: @NiklasB. So how will be the algorithm in C/C++ or other language? I still don't knok how to write that

Comment: Could you give a list of the 39 answers? In my code, I find it's 37. details: http://pastebin.com/1znijd0Y

Comment: @Sayakiss Why you have `0` in your answers ? The answers should be subsequences of an given array

Comment: @VasiuAlexandru `x y` means there is exactly y ways to product as x. so less or equals 40 = sum(1..40 y).

Comment: @Sayakiss `D = 50` not `40`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

Since `D` is relatively small, so we change the problem to:

`smaller and equal with D` => `equal with X(X = 1 to D)`.

The way to solve `equal with X`:

```
define f(x,n) = the number of the ways to product to `x` by using first n numbers.
```

And we will get:

```
f(x,n) = f(x, n-1) + f(x div a[n], n-1) (if x mod a[n] == 0)
```

Combining with memorization, we will get a O(D*n) solution.

Here is the code:

```
__author__ = 'Sayakiss'

global a, mem

#a = [2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 10]
a = [2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 27, 29, 31, 101, 103]
mem = {}

def solve(x):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        sum += f(i, len(a) - 1)
        #print str(i) + " " + str(f(i, len(a) - 1))
    return sum

def f(x, n):
    if x == 1:
        return 1
    if n == -1:
        return 0
    if mem.get((x, n)) is not None:
        return mem.get((x, n))
    result = 0
    if x % a[n] == 0:
        result += f(x / a[n], n - 1)
    result += f(x, n - 1)
    mem[(x, n)] = result
    return result

#print solve(50)
print solve(200000)
```

PS:

If there is any 1 in array `a`, my solution will fail. But it's easy to handle that, so you may do it by yourself.